# Spring Context Reference java

Tags: java, spring, reference, garbage-collection, applicationcontext

I know that in java, objects are eligible to be deleted by Garbage Collector if no reference refers to them.

So my question is : how spring can make spring bean available all time?

I think there is some object which refers all beans.
But these objects instead?

Maybe they are java Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ApplicationContext`'s `BeanFactory` (YMMV) has references to all the (non-prototype and some other scope) beans it creates, as well as all the utility objects it uses to create them.